# How do I sync RxJS updates so that intermediate values aren't passed through the stream?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

In my system I have a source, two "steps" that map the source to a new value, and then a sum that combines those two steps to create a final value. The initial run through of this system works as I hoped, generating a single sum of 3.

```
var source = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0);    
var stepOne = source.map(function (value) {
    return value + 1;
});
var stepTwo = source.map(function (value) {
    return value + 2;
});    
var sum = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    stepOne,
    stepTwo,
    function (s1, s2) {
        console.log('calc sum: ' + (s1 + s2));
        return s1 + s2;
    }).subscribe(function (sum) {
    });
```

Outputs:

```
> calc sum: 3
```

But if I then put in a new value for source I get two results like this:

```
source.onNext(1);

> calc sum: 4
> calc sum: 5
```

The first is an intermediate result… as the new source value passes through one part of the system, and then I get the final result when all values have finished propagating.

So my questions is, what's the recommended way to configure things so that a new value pushed into source will pass through the system atomically and only generate one sum result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `combineLatest` works, it indeed is confusing since it allows these temporarily inconsistent states as you pointed out. The key thing to learn from `combineLatest` is that it emits a new item whenever *any* one of its sources emits a new item, and it does so partially, it doesn't have any sort of "waiting" mechanism.

In diagrams, http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest.

What you probably want is the `zip` operator. Zip waits for its inputs to emit items that match with each other. In other words, zip's output emits its n-th item once all the n-th items from all inputs have been emitted. It is ideal for this diamond case where you have `source` generating `stepOne` and `stepTwo` and you want to combine `stepOne` and `stepTwo`.

In diagrams, http://rxmarbles.com/#zip.

Keep in mind that `zip` assumes the inputs have the same frequency of emissions. In other cases, you might want to combine items from stepOne with stepTwo when they have a different frequency of emissions. Then you need to use `combineLatest`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and link to http://rxmarbles.com. That was quite useful, and fun!

Comment: After more reading I've found that I can get the behavior that I was after using Bacon.js with it's [Glitch-free updates](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/issues/272) feature. I don't think RxJS has support for that, please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: RxJS doesn't, but that doesn't stop you from accomplishing whatever you need to. It will just be in a different way. Zip is the solution for most cases. Bacon.js also has heavy memory usage.